# Copy Rotation to bone fails

Tags: rigging

Im trying to make a controller to the hand, so I want to take the rotation of one bone, so I add a Copy Rotation to the hand and select that bone, but the result its not what I expected, its rotated 90º.

If I rotate the "origin rotation" bone 90 degrees it works, but I would like to not do that. 
I can change too the space to local parent, but then I have to rotate in Z to rotate the hand in Y and its weird.
Any help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure it's clear, maybe reformulate?

Comment: @moonboots as you can see when I add the modifier to copy the rotation and I select keep offset the bones are not like in the first image.

Comment: Still unclear, sorry, maybe share your file... The classic way to rig the hand is to parent it to the IK controller, now if you want your hand to stick to the lower arm, give it a Copy Location with the lower arm as Target, and a Head/Tail value of 1.

Comment: The problem its that I would like to use it in Unity as an humanoid, but Im having troubles for doing that